# Combinatorics, books arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

How many possibilities are there to arrange six hardcover books and four paperback books next to each other on a shelf? How many options are there if you are not allowed to have two paperback books next to each other?

I think that the answer for the first part of the question is
$$ \frac{(6 + 4)!}{6!4!}  = 210 $$
and it is clear for me why.

But I have problems with solving the second part.
So if 4 paperback books can't be together is it reasonable to think that it may be considered as one block? Like  $$ PHPHPHP $$ (P = paperback, H - hardcover) and rest like? $$3!$$

Anyone has tips? Thanks in advance...

Comment: In your answer, you seem to be treating all the hardcovers as indistinguishable; and all the paperbacks as indistinguishable. Is this is what is intended in the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both kind of books are $\color{red}{indistinguishable}$ , then first place $6$ hardcover books (this can be done only $1$ way because books are indistinguishable) and now there are $7$ possible place for papercovers to satisfy the condition ($\color{blue}{because}=-H-H-H-H-H-H-$ where H represents hardcover books and $\color{red}{-}$ represents possible places).. We can choose $4$ places in these $7$ places by $C(7,4)=35$ ways

If both kind of books are $\color{green}{distinguishable}$  then first place $6$ hardcover and they can be arrange among themselves by $6!$ ways.Moreover ,now there are $7$ possible place for papercovers to satisfy the condition ($\color{blue}{because}=-H-H-H-H-H-H-$ where H represents hardcover books and $\color{red}{-}$ represents possible places).

We can choose $4$ places in these $7$ places by $C(7,4)=35$ ways. What's more, these $4$ book can be aligned in among themselves by $4!$  ways. So , result is $6! \times C(7,4) \times 4!=604800$ different ways